Multiple Imputation for Missing Outcome Data
I have spent an extensive amount of time trying to understand the possible role of MICE in helping to "fill in" missing outcome data. I am relatively new to both multiple imputation and predictive modeling, so I appreciate your insight.
The problem: I have a dataset of clinician workforce density (# clinicians/100k people) for ~70% of countries. I want a complete dataset for all countries (this would allow us to provide a total # of clinicians globally), meaning I need to create imputations or predictions for the remaining countries. I have a number of covariates (~15). However, this covariate data is rarely complete for all countries. My understanding is that my ability to obtain outcome estimates for ALL missing countries via a traditional prediction model (using a train/test split) would be limited by the missing covariate data.
My solution: My thought was instead to use MICE to impute the missing outcome variable, clinician density, for each country.
IF this is a valid use for MICE, my question is then how to obtain the outcome variable (workforce density). I have created m multiply imputed datasets. I understand that I should not take the average of these datasets or select an individual dataset. I haven't found a publication that clearly explains the next step as MICE seems to be used more to obtain regression coefficients than the data itself. My plan is to create the pooled regression model using covariates with complete data (which limits the covariates I can use) and then use that regression model to "predict" the missing country workforce densities.
Is this reasonable, or is there a better way to do this?

Two comments: 1) one country = 1 line, meaning that your data is small? 2) Conceptually, you "only" need to impute all columns, including the response. No additional model is required to fill the response. And then: If you repeat the imputation multiple times, you would show the averaged values as estimates, using their standard deviation/error(?) as uncertainty.

Correct, 1 country = 1 line. Thank you!
